# How to toggle neotree in the project directory?

Tags: files

There is a nice example of how to open neotree in the project root
see:
 https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree (`find-file-in-project` and `Projectile` sections).

However, I'd like to **toggle** neotree, so I can easily open and close it, while having the root set to the project path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a slightly modified version of [this post](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/149#issuecomment-263074312), I managed to get this working:

```el
(defun my-neotree-project-dir-toggle ()
  "Open NeoTree using the project root, using projectile, find-file-in-project,
or the current buffer directory."
  (interactive)
  (require 'neotree)
  (let* ((filepath (buffer-file-name))
         (project-dir
          (with-demoted-errors "neotree-project-dir-toggle error: %S"
              (cond
               ((featurep 'projectile)
                (projectile-project-root))
               ((featurep 'find-file-in-project)
                (ffip-project-root))
               (t ;; Fall back to version control root.
                (if filepath
                    (vc-call-backend
                     (vc-responsible-backend filepath) 'root filepath)
                  nil)))))
         (neo-smart-open t))

    (if (and (fboundp 'neo-global--window-exists-p)
             (neo-global--window-exists-p))
        (neotree-hide)
      (neotree-show)
      (when project-dir
        (neotree-dir project-dir))
      (when filepath
        (neotree-find filepath)))))
```

Key binding to toggle, example:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-e") 'my-neotree-project-dir-toggle)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's now 2020 and you can open neotree in the current directory using `neotree-show` instead of `neotree-toggle`.

`neotree-show` does exactly what the orignal op required, without the need for the elaborate function.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but found this still not quite as good as `neotree-toggle` snippet. As it doesn't show a tree for the paths leading up to the current file. Also, looking at the code, it doesn't support `find-file-in-project` or `vc` methods of finding the root.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, on neotree v 0.5.1. The definition of `neotree-open` has built-in integration with projectile, and it is wrapped by `neotree-toggle` which answers the original question.

Comment: @ideasman42 I have opened a PR adding the built-in project integration: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/pull/343 -- thanks for your comment.